# How to hide blinking text cursor in GRUB (boot)

Tags: debian, boot, grub, cursor

I use this setting, but still see cursor before launch plymouth in debian 10

```
RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=0 splash"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding the kernel parameter

```
vt.global_cursor_default=0
```

to the GRUB parameter line (see, e.g. the [Kernel Admin Guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) or [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot) article).

Comment: It is not work, i see cursor after grub menu and before plymouth

Comment: Hm, that is strange. Unfortunately, I do not know of any other way so far ..

Comment: Ok, no important for now. Need to do make bug report to GRUB2?

Comment: I don't think this would be a case for a GRUB bug report because the parameters from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` are passed to the linux kernel. As long as we have no reason to suspect that the parameter is "lost" before being passed to the linux kernel (try looking in `journalctl -b` for hints that the parameter is set correctly), that would rather be a case for a bug report to the Linux kernel developers (but that should be done with caution and after extensive checking that the problem is not on the user side ...).

Comment: When use vt.cur_default=1 cursor hide after plymouth and before show lightdm, but i still see black background in corner

Comment: Just an FYI, but this also works for Raspberry Pi if you append this to the `/boot/cmdline.txt`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add to grub config /etc/default/grub kernel parameter

A) Use in real hardware

```
vt.cur_default=1
```

B) Use in VirtualBox

```
vt.cur_default=50
```

2. Uncomment

   GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
3. Add the line

   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
4. Update changes

   update-grub

I found it when [investigate](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/32309) parameter vga=current on [Silent boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot) parameter which [deprecated](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubTransition)

Comment: P.S. black background in corner still exist. Welcome new solution to fix it

Comment: Usage vt.cur_default=50 fix for me black background. See manual for this parameter to undertake why